# Package installation problems when using Python 3.12 and pip version 24.0

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, failed-installation, installation-package

I am using Python 3.12, pip version 24.0 and setuptools version 69.2.0. The setup.py file given with the package does not work as the .egg files are deprecated. These is a discussion about this at pypa/pip#12297. I have tried not to use the setup.py and instead use `pip install` but I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1u7gh_7i\overlay
\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\util.py", line 139, in convert_path
raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname)
ValueError: path '/home/esabellico/workspace/confluent-kafka-python-sdist/
LICENSE.txt' cannot be absolute
```

I have gone inside of util.py file but it is hard to follow exactly what is going on and why installation terminates. I have spent two full days trying to install this particular package but have not had any luck. All feedback, fixes, updates, or suggestions are hightly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could format your post so it's more readable. On the surface it looks like you're trying to install a package in py312 that doesn't support py312? You either need to revert to a supported version of python, wait for the package maintainers to support py312 or fork the original project and do it yourself?

Comment: Yes sorry about the messy post. It was running with py3.9 happily but for other reasons I had to update python to its latest version and then it stopped working.  I have found a work around.  Thanks for your time.